# How to define once a component in Jest and Enzyme?

Tags: javascript, jestjs, tdd, enzyme

I'm using jest and enzyme to handle test cases in my application. For example I've an `App` component and I want to write 2 case tests for that:

```js
describe('App Component', () => {

  test('Render without error', () => {
    const wrapper = shallow(<App />);
  });

  test('Check title tag', () => {
    const wrapper = shallow(<App />);
    const title = wrapper.find('h1');
    expect(title.text()).toBe('App');
  });

});
```

In above code, I've written twice `const wrapper = shallow(<App />);` to define component.

So, Is there any trick to define the `wrapper` once and use that more?

Or, That's correct and hasn't any performance issue?

I'd like to learn best practices actually!

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Your approach it's correct since each test needs to `shallow` the component and check some stuff. There are any performance issues here! If you want a tip, try to think a bit more about the test titles, i.e:

`Render without error` could be `it renders`

`Check title tag` could be `title tag is equal to "App"`

Comment: so, there is not problem to write `const wrapper = shallow(<App />);` for each tests?

Comment: Nope, you should do it like this. Each test should have a clean `shallow` of the component, otherwise if some test already modified something, the next could not check some stuff correctly, because it is already executed.

Answer (score 0):

In this case can be:

```
  let wrapper;

  beforeEach(() => {
    wrapper = shallow(<App />);
  });
  ...
```

This won't work for tests that need to instantiate a component with different props, or do something before it's instantiated, then `wrapper` assignment needs to be moved to tests.